# How to use the zgrep command for "grep -f file1 file2"?

Tags: linux

I have list of numbers in `file1` and want to search for these numbers in `file2.gz`, `file3.gz`, etc.

Example:

file1:

```
123,
456,
678
```

`file22.gz` and `file23.gz` might contain the numbers of file1. We need to search and get the results.

I checked manual pages but, somehow could not find the answer.

Also please provide diff options for it:

If the `file22` and `file23` are plain files, then I got the answer like

```
grep -f file1 file2*.txt
```

but the samething unable to find using zgrep.